# Arduino problems:" 'i' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c, arduino, scope, declaration, arduino-uno

Having alot of problems with this code that is made for an arduino reaction game. I am not sure if I maybe have declared i twice or something. Arduino tells me that the problem is here: "if ( i == success_led )".

```
// Public Domain 2012 by A.Coster

// some constants for readability, using booleans to save memory
boolean ON  = 1 ;
boolean OFF = 0 ;

// Arduino pin setup - there are 3 pins used for LEDs,
// 1 for push-button. The pin at index success_led is
// the one the user should try to hit.
byte led_pins[3]       = {8,9,10} ;
byte button_pin        =    2 ;
byte success_led       =    1 ;  // refers to pin 9

// time_change is the number of milliseconds to add upon
// failure or subtract upon success.
// colorswitch_delay is the amount of time that the LED stays
// on. This value has time_change added to/subtracted from it.
// So that the user knows which LED was lit up when they hit
// the button, push_pause defines the number of milliseconds
// that the LED will stay on after the button is pressed.
unsigned int time_change       =   50 ;
unsigned int colorswitch_delay =  500 ;
unsigned int push_pause        = 2000 ;

void setup(){

    for (int i=0 ; i ;) ;      
    pinMode( led_pins[i], OUTPUT ) ;

    pinMode( button_pin, INPUT ) ;
}

void loop(){
    // need to keep track of button presses
    // so set the button state to 0 and overwrite
    // later upon button press
    boolean button_state = OFF ;

    // sequentially turn on each LED
    for ( int i=0 ; i        digitalWrite( led_pins[i], HIGH ) ;

        // Check for a button press every 5 milliseconds
        for ( int t=0 ; t            button_state = digitalRead( button_pin ) ;

            // if the button has been pressed, stop
            // switching LEDs so the user knows, and
            // then check if it was the success_led
            if ( button_state == ON ){
                delay( push_pause ) ;

                // set the button state back to off
                button_state = OFF ;
                if ( i == success_led )
                    // if the user hit the right LED,
                    // make it more challenging by
                    // reducing the delay between LED
                    // switches.
                    colorswitch_delay -= time_change ;
                else
                    // if the user was wrong, make it
                    // easier by increasing the delay.
                    colorswitch_delay += time_change ;
                    break ;
                }
            delay( 5 ) ;
        }
        // and turn it off before looping through
        // to turn the next LED on.
        digitalWrite( led_pins[i], LOW ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems broken and won't compile due to bad grammer around `for` token. Is this code really what you are working on?

Comment: Looks like you blindly copy/pasted code from the interwebs, including the copyright header... without even trying to see if the syntax was at all valid. Think before you copy/paste.

Comment: A basic `for` loop is `for (int i = 0; i < XXX; i++) { your code here}` with XXX the number of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed semicolons after each `for` loop. As result variable `i` (and some other variables) declared in the control statements of the loops is not alive outside these statements. For example

```
void setup(){

    for (int i=0 ; i ;) ;      
                       ^^^
    pinMode( led_pins[i], OUTPUT ) ;
                     ^^^???
    //...
```

or

```
void loop(){
    // need to keep track of button presses
    // so set the button state to 0 and overwrite
    // later upon button press
    boolean button_state = OFF ;

    // sequentially turn on each LED
    for ( int i=0 ; i        digitalWrite( led_pins[i], HIGH ) ;
                                                              ^^^
        // Check for a button press every 5 milliseconds
        for ( int t=0 ; t            button_state = digitalRead( button_pin ) ;
                                                                             ^^^
        //...
```